# cPanel cron job not executing Magento cron script but works manually

Tags: php, magento, cron, cpanel, magento-1.9

I have a Magento store hosted on a cPanel server. Although I have the following cron job setup, it doesn't seem to do anything, with no errors reported anywhere:

```
php /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

When I execute this from SSH manually, it works every time (and the cron_schedule table updates). I have checked the permissions for both cron.php and cron.sh and compared them with other installations that do work, and everything looks correct.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting cron job using `wget` command. Following is example for the same.

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null http://www.domain.com/cron.php
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Actually the whole problem was caused by something weird going on with the cron.php and cron.sh files. I posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, when I copied the cron.php and cron.sh from another installation in a subfolder of the account, it started working normally. I really don't know why the original files caused this behavior; the permissions and ownership of the files were identical, as were the contents.